# How to prevent auto-placement to edge columns in CSS grid

Tags: css, css-grid

I'm trying to implement an experimental 12 column grid system using CSS grids. I wish to keep the margins outside the grid as separate columns so that I may bleed the contents of the edge columns into them, a feature notoriously difficult to achieve using traditional grid systems.

My problem is that CSS grid's auto-placement wants to place content in the margin columns. My first thought was to create pseudo-elements for the grid margins that span all the rows of the grid but `grid-row-end: -1` only works on the explicit grid rows and not the ones created automatically.

Is there a way to either make the grid cell span all the rows in the implicit grid, or otherwise prevent auto-placement from using the edge columns?

**Note**: The snippet only works in the newest versions of Chrome, FF and Safari.

```css
.grid {
  background-color: #ccc;
  margin: 1em 0;

  display: grid;
  grid-auto-flow: row;
  grid-template-columns: [main-start] 1em [content-start] repeat(12, 1fr) [content-end] 1em [main-end];
  grid-gap: 1em;
}

.grid__col-12 {
  grid-column: span 12;
}

.grid__col-6 {
  grid-column: span 6;
}

.grid__col-4 {
  grid-column: span 4;
}

.grid::before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  grid-column: main-start / content-start;
  grid-row: 1 / -1; /* Doesn't work */
  background-color: #ffeeee;
}

.grid::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  grid-column: content-end / main-end;
  grid-row: 1 / -1; /* Doesn't work */
  background-color: #ffeeee;
}

.grid.faked::before, .grid.faked::after {
  grid-row: 1 / 4; /* Hardcoded for line amount */
}

.col {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
```

```html
<p>What I want:</p>
<div class="grid faked">
  <div class="col grid__col-12">12</div>
  <div class="col grid__col-6">6</div>
  <div class="col grid__col-6">6</div>
  <div class="col grid__col-4">4</div>
  <div class="col grid__col-4">4</div>
  <div class="col grid__col-4">4</div>
</div>

<p>What I got:</p>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="col grid__col-12">12</div>
  <div class="col grid__col-6">6</div>
  <div class="col grid__col-6">6</div>
  <div class="col grid__col-4">4</div>
  <div class="col grid__col-4">4</div>
  <div class="col grid__col-4">4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the purpose of the pseudos, design ? if so, then use background to draw them http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/GWLQwG (made simpler)

Comment: @GCyrillus, the purpose is to mark the leftmost and rightmost column as occupied so the auto-placement algorithm doesn't place cells there. The color is just for visualization.

Comment: `padding: 0 30px` on the grid container?

Comment: @Michael_B, that would prevent me from assigning content to the edge cells unless I provide a negative margin - and that won't work on large screens when the grid reaches maximum width and gets centered.